# django - how to save modified form without overriding original entry

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a logical "how to" or best practices problem.

**A simplified example**

I have a model class with an textbox. Users can add new entries but they will only be displayed for other users if the admin accepts them.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    # Relation to a user
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    # Simple textbox as example attribute
    text = TextArea()
    # Admin has to accept the entry that other users can see it
    accepted = BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Problem**

I would like to let users modify a listing, but the admin has to accept them first. As long as the admin hasn't accept the modification it should still show the old unmodified version of the entry.

**My Approaches**

**a)** create a new class

```
class MyEditClass(models.Model)
    # ForeignKey to the original class
    fk = ForeignKey(MyClass)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    text = TextArea()
    accepted = BooleanField(default=False)
```

The modifications gets saved in a new table/class. If the admin accepts this modified entry the original entry becomes this one.

*Why I don't like it?* My class has about 60 attributes with a lot of relations. As I haven't found a solution to duplicate a complete class this produces a lot of duplicated lines of code. If I add a new attr. in `MyClass` I also have to add it in `MyEditClass` ...

**b)** Add a new atrribute to `MyClass` if entry got edited

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    # new attribute with the primary key of the edited field
    edited_pk = PositiveIntegerField(default=None, blank=True, none=True)
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    text = TextArea()
    accepted = BooleanField(default=False)
```

In this case you don't create a new class, instead you save the edited entries in the same class and add the attribute `edited_pk`. If a entry is a new entry set `edited_pk = None` (default). If a User modifies an entry get the pk from the original entry. Then add the modified one as a new entry with `edited_pk = original_entry.pk`. If the admin accepts the modified version, the original entry gets overridden with the modified one.

*Why I don't like this solution?* As Admin I would like to have a single class in the backend to accept modified entries.

Do you have any other (maybe already bultin or 3rd party) approaches?

Thanks in advance

(Title is bad, but I can't find a better name. Please edit if you do so)

**Solution**

If you don't want to use a 3rd Party app check the marked answer.

My favorite solution, also by *Obj3ctiv3_C_88* needs [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).
Therefore I created a method:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(User)
    text = TextArea()
    accepted = BooleanField(default=False)
    history = HistoricalRecords()  # rtd from django-simple-history

    def get_accepted(self):
        """Return the first entry from the history which is accepted."""
        return self.history.filter(accepted=True).first()
```

in your views:

```
# This code may be optimized, but for now it works
items = MyClass.objects.all()
items = list(items)  # convert queryset to a list
i = 0
for item in items:
    # Important to get the instance. Otherwise custom methods won't work
    items[i] = item.get_accepted().instance
    i += 1
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history

Comment: That's a great app. I tried it and it tracks all the changes and I can revert them. The only (important) thing I haven't figuered out: Is it possible to not save the changes immediately? The admin should be able to approve the new entry.

Comment: No but you could have an approved field (boolean) and get the latest where approved=True from simple history to display on your site and for approval look where approved = False in your model (setting it to True if you approve which would update state in simple history).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    unapproved = models.Charfield(max_length=1000, default=None, Blank=True)
    approved = models.Charfield(max_length=1000, default=None, Blank=True)

# on submit
BlogComment.unapproved = request.POST['user_comment']

# on approve
BlogComment.approved = BlogComment.unapproved
BlogComment.unapproved = None
BlogComment.save()
```

This would allow you to keep 2 distinct states for the same comment. You only render the BlogComment.approved. For find the comments which need approval you just filter(~Q(unapproved = None))

Comment: Nice approve. I will try it immediately.

Comment: marked as correct, even if I prefer the solution with django-simple-history